# Same column in multiple foreign overlapping foreign keys - good practise?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

My problem is easy to explain, and I have a solution for it I came up with myself, but I am not sure if it may cause conflicts later on so that's why I am putting it here.

I have a table Van. The vans in question are owned by technicians, and filled with parts, that have to be registered.
Every bus has two Stocks (composed of parts). An Administrative Stock, which is how much the van *should* have (say, a van is supposed to have twenty of a type of bolt), and one is the Actual Stock, which is how many have been counted.

Now, both types of Stock are Weak Entities of the Van. They inherit VanName, Van's primary identifier, and then have an attribute UpdateTime. Those two together form both types of Stock's primary identifiers.

To sum it up:

```
Van
PK: VanName

ActualStock
PK: VanName, UpdateMoment
FK: VanName (Van.VanName)

AdministrativeStock
PK: VanName, UpdateMoment
FK: VanName (Van.VanName)
```

Now here comes the questionable part. I want to make a Report, listing the differences between a certain ActualStock and a certain AdministrativeStock of the same van (part count differences). It is defined by both the Van it reports on, the ActualStock it used, and the AdministrativeStock it used to compare to.

So, the most "correct" way I know would be to structure the table like this:

```
Report
PK: VanName, ActualStockUpdateMoment, ActualStockVanName, AdministrativeStockUpdateMoment, AdministrativeStockVanName
FK: VanName (Van.VanName)
FK: ActualStockUpdateMoment (ActualStock.UpdateMoment), ActualStockVanName (ActualStock.VanName)
FK: AdministrativeStockUpdateMoment(AdministrativeStock.UpdateMoment), AdministrativeStockVanName(AdministrativeStock.VanName)
```

Meaning I would be inheriting the same VanName thrice, and by definition the three entries must be identical. That just sounds like such a waste to me.

So I wonder if I can do it like this instead.

```
Report:
PK: VanName, ActualStockUpdateMoment, AdministrativeStockUpdateMoment
FK: VanName (Van.VanName)
FK: ActualStockUpdateMoment (ActualStock.UpdateMoment), VanName (ActualStock.VanName)
FK: AdministrativeStockUpdateMoment (AdministrativeStock.UpdateMoment), VanName (AdministrativeStock.VanName)
```

So the same column becomes part of three different foreign keys.

Is that good practise or not? Will I run into trouble if I do this? (assuming a Report will always only be between Stocks of the same Van)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing wrong with that.

There's a somewhat nitpicky remark to make that the first FK (VanName) is presumably superfluous since that would normally already be implied by the other two (plus the presumable fact that the referenced tables there have themselves an FK that guarantees the existence of VanName).

Comment: Ah, the VanName one I didn't think of!